# GDB script to trace Objective-C calls on iOS device - issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, gdb, objective-c-runtime

I have a gdb script I am working on to trace all objective-C method calls that pass through objc_msgSend but Ive encountered a problem I cant seem to deal with. After review of the Objective-C runtime source code I have developed the following script to print [  ] at each break on objc_msgSend. The issue is that there are situations in which data_NEVER_USE is not a valid pointer but is also not null. The only indicator that I can find of whether a class is initialized is in id->data_NEVER_USE->flags & RW_REALIZED. What aspect of class initialization am I missing here that would allow me to skip this case?

```
b objc_msgSend
c
commands
silent

if (*$r0 == 0)
    continue
end

set $id = (class_t *)$r0
set $sel = $r1      
print *$id  
if($id->data_NEVER_USE != 0)
    set $data = (class_ro_t *) ($id->data_NEVER_USE)
    if (($data->flags & 0x80000000) && ($data->name))
        set $classname = $data->name
        printf "[%s ", $classname
    else
        continue
    end
end

if ($sel != 0)
    printf "%s", $sel
else
    printf "null"
end

printf "]\n"
continue
end
```

I appreciate any help on this. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately using the simulator is not an option. The most useful approach for me is one that allows tracing on a physical device, without access to source code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These 2 methods have worked reasonably well for me. Note that in my example I am manually starting "SomeApp" in order to monitor it as soon as it starts up.

```
gdb
(gdb) attach --waitfor 'SomeApp'

**this is where you manually start SomeApp on your device**

call (void)instrumentObjcMessageSends(YES)
```

The "instrumentObjcMessageSends" enables/disables message logging from within the runtime. Here's some [more information on this method.](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2006/04/22/tracing_objc/)

Another option, again still using GDB on your iDevice, is to write a small command like this:

```
FooPad:~ root# gdb
(gdb) attach SBSettings
Attaching to process 440.
Reading symbols for shared libraries . done
Reading symbols for shared libraries ............................. done
0x35686004 in mach_msg_trap ()

(gdb) break objc_msgSend
Breakpoint 1 at 0x3323ef72

(gdb) commands
Type commands for when breakpoint 1 is hit, one per line.
End with a line saying just "end".

>printf "-[%s %s]\n", (char *)class_getName(*(long *)$r0,$r1),$r1
>c
>end

(gdb) c
Continuing.
// a ton of information will follow
```

As soon as you press **"c"** (right above line that reads "Continuing.", your screen will fill with function names and arguments.

And finally follow [these instructions](http://www.securitylearn.net/2012/05/20/installing-gnu-debugger-on-iphone/) to get a working GDB on your iDevice. For posterity I'll post the short instructions here:

> GNU Debugger (gdb) is used to analyze the run time behavior of an iOS
>   application. In recent iOS versions, GNU Debugger directly downloaded
>   from the Cydia is broken and not functioning properly. Following the
>   Pod 2g blog post also did not help me.
>
> To get rid of this problem, add http://cydia.radare.org to cydia
>   source and download the latest GNU Debugger (build 1708). GDB build
>   1708 is working for iOS 5.x.